# Find IDs where values are only in array

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
ID | Value
-----------------
1 | red
1 | black

2 | green
2 | black
```

> array('green', 'orange', 'black');

And I need to get the result ID: `2`

Can someone save my life, please?

Comment: what you want, a query that fetches the record based on the values of array..is that all?

Comment: What's the rule/requirement that should be followed? Angelo's post will literally give you the answer you need, though if there's a rule to be followed, another approach might be possible... just saying :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE value IN ('green', 'orange', 'black')
      AND id NOT IN (
          SELECT id
          FROM table
          WHERE value NOT IN ('green', 'orange', 'black'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
group by id
having sum(case when value IN ('green', 'orange', 'black') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when value NOT IN ('green', 'orange', 'black') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```